# Typescript: run JavaScript contained in string

Tags: typescript

I have a string that contains *multiple* JavaScript methods.  I want to be able to convert this JavaScript into callable functions within my TypeScript code.

Ex:

```
script = 'function func1 () { console.log("func1"); } function func2 () { console.log("func2"); }';
// ...
// Magic
// ...
func1();
```

Comment: Not much you can do besides creating a separate file with that content, you would also have to export the two functions...

Comment: Basically: [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Eval will not allow TypeScript to call it, it doesn't have access to the definitions

Comment: What is the point here exactly? If you have functions that you're actually going to call in your code, **hardcoded**, then why put them in a string?

Comment: @NitzanTomer  This is simplified version.  I need to get a script from the web (which is dynamic) and use functions from that script.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Got it to work.  eval was the answer but it had to be accessed from the native window object.  window.eval(script);